# Identify the pattern of terms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, fractions

Here is an exam question of the unit infinite series and series of functions.

> Identify the pattern of terms and determine whether the following
> series is convergent
>
> $$1 -1+\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} \cdots$$

Am I supposed to find the $n^{th}$ term?

Are there any method of finding a simple general term for the series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of this series is $0$.

For example for $n\geq3$ the general term is $$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2\left[\frac{n-1}{2}\right]}$$

For an even $n$ we have $S_n=0$, while for an odd $n$ we have $S_n=\frac{1}{\frac{n+1}{2}}\rightarrow0.$

Comment: How do you prove it? can you give a general term for the series?

Comment: @Sahan Aloka Mendis I added something. See now.

Comment: for n=4, isn't the answer  -$\frac{1}{3}$? according to your general term?

Comment: @Sahan Aloka Mendis For $n=4$ we obtain $-\frac{1}{2}$ because $\left[\frac{3}{2}\right]=1.$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the partial sums.

We have that $S_N = 0$ when $N=2k$ and $S_N = \frac 1{k}$ when $N = 2k-1$. Now obviously we have that $S_N \to 0$ and so the series converges to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the first $n$ terms of your series is$$\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }n\text{ is even}\\\frac1k&\text{ if }n=2k-1\text{ for some }k\in\mathbb{N}.\end{cases}$$Therefore, the sum of your series, which is, by definition, the limit of the partial sums, is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of partial sum of the series, is $$ 1,0,1/2,0,1/3,0,....$$ Which is simply  $$ S n = \frac{1-(-1)^n}{n+1}$$ Therefore the series converges to $0.$